# Keyboard covers focused input field in forms within Angular Material dialog component in mobile devices

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, android-softkeyboard

I have a form inside an Angular Material Dialog component. My problem is that when an input field gets focus, the keyboard opening in mobile devices covers the input field the user wants to write into.

When the keyboard opens the main body of the HTML gets az appropriate margin-bottom, however, this does not apply to the dialog's wrapper (cdk-overlay-container), since it's position is fixed.

My ideas:
1, Changing from fixed to absolute could solve my problem, however since my main container is a huge scroll-container, that would only work if I scroll to the top programmatically, which I don't really like.

2, If I could detect that a keyboard was opened, I could add a class to a parent container, however, I'm not sure how to do this without attaching an event to every input field we have, which feels ugly and unnecessarily heavy (since I'd have to send events to notify other components). I would also need to know the size of the keyboard, which I'm not sure is possible.

The issue occurs on both Android and iOS.

Comment: 3.-You can always in a component with a formControl enclosed all by a < div class="container keyboard">..< /div> where .container.keyboard{ margin-bottom:18rem;}

Comment: If you don't want to open the keyboard, you can pass the `autoFocus='false'` option when you open the dialog via the MatDilogConfig object.

Comment: @G.Tranter Sorry I might have been unclear, the keyboard opening automatically is not the issue. The issue is that when the user needs it (and opens it), it covers the input field the user writes into.

Comment: @Eliseo If I understand correctly, that would mean that the keyboard has to be open even when the input field isn't in focus. This isn't acceptable for us right now, but thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: @barney.balazs. Really your problem looks like one own. Some of my component was very short, so when the keyboard has to be openen, this cover part of the controls and I have no "scroll". The only solution that I found was make the component heigher, so adding this "height" to the margin bottom. But not, when the controls lost the focus, the keyboard hide automatically. I was thinked that your problem was like that mine

Comment: @barney.balazs did you manage to resolve this issue somehow ? Any workaround ?

Comment: @maran Sadly no, it's still the same in my app.

Comment: @barney.balazs I resolved mine. Turns out it was my mistake in setting up dialog. In my case dialog had height attribute set to auto. Turning this into min specific height of say.. 36rem for me allowed for keyboard to be raised but automatically scroll down to the field as it should natively and doesn't cover it no more. That's my two cents.. seems fine and as intended so there's that.